# Set style on individual Vaadin tree item

Tags: css, tree, vaadin, styling

In a Vaadin tree component I want to be able to in real time add and remove styling on specific items using its itemId.

I've looked through the tree component and searched for similar questions, but In haven't found anything. Does anyone have an idea of how to achieve this?

**EDIT**

I found a solution to the question some time ago but Nils reminded me with his answer that I never updated. This was my solution.

```
customerTree.setItemStyleGenerator(new Tree.ItemStyleGenerator() {

    @Override
    public String getStyle(Object itemId) {
        Item item = customerTree.getItem(itemId);

        String itemName =
            item.getItemProperty("name").getValue().toString().toLowerCase();
        return itemName.equals(filter) ? "bold" : "clear";
    }
});
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can do this with a Tree.ItemStyleGenerator:

```
Tree myTree = new Tree();
myTree.setItemStyleGenerator(new ItemStyleGenerator() {
    @Override
    public String getStyle(Object itemId) {
        return itemId.equals("foo") ? "foo" : "bar";
    }
});
```

Comment: Hi Nils! Thanks, I had already found a solution to this question however. But it's good of you to remind me. I've edited in my solution in the OP and it's very similar to yours, logically identical more ore less.